# Entity Framework references no included

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a layered application, Presentation (MVC), Business and Data, which shared libraries across them all. A developer had a reference to the Entity Framework in the presentation code.

Although this is bad, all worked. I have now asked that this reference be removed, but now we get an error at the data access layer:

> "System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded"

I have looked around and it seems to be because the 'System.Data.SqlClient is not being 'packaged' when we run the solution. I also found a 'solution' where you make reference to something, and this makes Visual Studio include the required references:

```
Type _Temp = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);
```

You never use this _Temp thing... it's just so that VS knows to include certain references.

Is this a valid fix? Is it a hack? Is there a better way to do this, other than to re-include EF references in the presentation?

Comment: So you were using Entity Framework, and now you don't want to use it?

Comment: No, we're using EF, but only in the data access layer. When removing any reference to EF from the presentation, the application fails at runtime with the error above. The presentation should not have any service reference to the EF.

Comment: Your presentation layer should not reference Entity Framework. Remove anything in that layer that tries to use EF. Including that line.

Comment: Yes, this has been done. And my application starts fine. However, when the first call gets bade to the database, via the DAL, it errors when trying to connect the EF to the database with the error above. The Data Access layer fails, as it can't reference some 'References'. But if I create the fake reference (Shown in the post above), all works fine. So all reference removed from the presentation... no attempted data access, except for the methods in the DAL. But they're failing.\

Comment: How are you pulling in library dependencies? NuGet? Or loose DLL's?

Comment: I'm not sure. It works if I make a dummy reference to "typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices)". Removing that line, seems to lose some dependecies (Or make  Visual studio THINK we don't need the dependencies). I'm not even sure which reference it's losing at the moment, but it seems to think we don't need one of them. EF was installed via NuGet.

Comment: Did you check in the config file?

Comment: Which version of the Entityframework are you using in each layer. Check if  they are different in each layer of your project.